# How can http:// be changed to abc:// and can wireshark capture this traffic?

Tags: url, types, url-routing, protocols, network-protocols

I've seen this before, but never knew how it is accomplished.

What is the http for? Does it direct my request? Is this related to MIME Types? How is it like saying ftp:// ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://` `ftp://` `file://` etc. are some of many [URI Schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

You're not mentioning any specific application so it's hard to answer your questions. Basicaly the URI scheme tells the application that handles to URI what is the URI for and what protocol should be used.

For example the web browsers support many protocols including HTTP, FTP, direct local file access etc. You can tell your browser to open `file://path/to/local/file.html` and it'll access the file from disk. You can also tell it to open `ftp://server/path/to/file.html` and it'll load the file from FTP server.

It's allowed to have any scheme you like in your application. For example a lot of mobile applications handle their URI schemes like `fb://` for facebook or `instagram://` for instagram.

Wireshark can capture any network traffic regardless of the URI scheme used. It works on low network layer and can capture even 'raw' wifi or ethernet traffic (that's huge simplification - please refer to the course mentioned in my profile bio)